# How to get display name from created by field in sharepoint client object model?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query

In my SharePoint JavaScript code, I am retrieving items from a list in my SP 2010 environment. I used a camel query to download specific fields. One of the fields was `created by` (person who created the item). When I loop through the items, I get the value of the created by field, and if I try to insert it into the dom, it says `[object Object]`.

So I think there is a method I need to call on that object how I don't know what it is. I just want to get the display name from it as a string.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Can we see some of your code? Perhaps it is an spuserobject and you need to get the name property. var user = yourobject.Name ?

Comment: Well I am getting the field using the column name `Author`. Also is there a way using any developer tools, to see what the datatype of this object is?

Answer (score 1):

I got it, you need to use this method `.get_lookupValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the right field...

```
    function findItems()
{
    var soapEnv =   "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> <soap:Body>" + 
                    "<GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>" +
                        "<listName>listNameHere</listName>" +
                        "<query> <Query> <Where>" +
                            "<Eq> <FieldRef Name='Assignee'/> <Value Type='Text'>" + variableName+ "</Value> </Eq>" +
                        "</Where> </Query> </query>" +
                        "<viewFields> <ViewFields> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </ViewFields> </viewFields>" +
                        "<rowLimit>99999</rowLimit>" +
                        "<queryOptions xmlns:SOAPSDK9='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' > <QueryOptions/> </queryOptions>" + 
                    "</GetListItems>" +
                "</soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
    url: "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: ProcessListItems,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}

function ProcessListItems(xData, status) {
    var createdBy;

    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
        createdBy= $(this).attr("ows_Author");
        alert(createdBy);
    });
}
```

The createdBy variable at the end, for example, will be the person who created the item.  ows_Editor should be the last "Modified By" person

Comment: I am coding it different, I am doing it like the examples from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx.